# CKEditor: display indicator for page break

Tags: javascript, css, plugins, ckeditor, frontend

We do use CKEditor in a SaaS system that is meant to produce Presentation material (think Powerpoint but on the Web, basically). We actually produce "slides" with a CKEditor.

A slide has a definite height in our specific case. The height will not be dynamic, we know beforehand how high (in pixel) an article typed into CKEditor will need to be before being cut off in the Presentation.

Problem: we want a sort of live display, like a red line or something alike, that shows when the page is going to break; so that the user typing into CKEditor gets a feeling of when the breaks are going to come (I an not talking about putting the breaks in there manually, just having a display of when breaks naturally occur).

How should we tackle the problem with CKEditor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that your slide height must be 500px.
Create an empty transparent PNG image with width 1px and height 500px. Make the last 2-3 pixels red. This will indicate the page break.
Then, find `contents.css` inside your CKEditor folder and modify the `.cke_editable` section to include `background-image: url('page_break_indicator.png');` which will add the image as a background that will be repeated both horizontally and vertically.
But beware that when a user creates 3 or more slides and then modifies a slide that's not the last, all other slides that come after it must be checked according to their page breaks.

Comment: I understand the idea but it has a problem, which is: when editing in said editor, while the height is known, the width, however is not known. It is dynamic. Meaning: if I type a sentence on my extra wide screen, it could end up on multiple lines in the Presentation (which actually does have both set width and height - the presentation later lands inside a PDF)

Comment: I assumed from your question that you had a static width for CKEditor. You can do this: find through testing the optimum width (let's say 900px) that CKEditor should have in order for the resulting pdf to be the same. Then, in your configuration file use `config.width = 900;` for a static width and use either `config.resize_enabled = false;` to disable resizing or `config.resize_dir = 'vertical';` to only allow vertical resizing. Also, use `config.removePlugins = 'maximize';` to disable maximizing.

Comment: I have accepted your answer Wizard, but we have postponed the feature in the end (time reasons).